# How to turn off the alarm?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

My App goes like this:

- When you first start the app, you'll see a button. Connecting or disconnecting the AC charger doesn't affect anything until you hit that **Start** button.
- When you tap the **Start** button, the "service" is started.
- Now if you remove the AC charger you will hear an alarm sound.
- Connecting the AC with the device again should stop the alarm but it does **NOT**.
- Now removing the AC again starts another alarm. The alarms overlap.

Can you help me find the bug?

**Thanks**

My work so far:

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.yousef.mustafa.antitheft">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/antitheft"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/antitheft"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionReceiver">

        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button startServiceButton;
    PowerConnectionReceiver powerConnectionReceiver;
    BroadcastReceiver powerDisconnectedBroadcastReceiver;
    BroadcastReceiver powerConnectedBroadcastReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        powerConnectionReceiver = new PowerConnectionReceiver(true);
        startServiceButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.startServiceButton);

        powerDisconnectedBroadcastReceiver = new PowerConnectionReceiver(true);
        powerConnectedBroadcastReceiver = new PowerConnectionReceiver(false);

        startServiceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (startServiceButton.isActivated()) {
                    unregisterReceiver(powerDisconnectedBroadcastReceiver);
                    unregisterReceiver(powerConnectedBroadcastReceiver);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startServiceButton.setActivated(false);
                } else {
                    monitorBatteryChanges();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void monitorBatteryChanges() {

        IntentFilter powerDisconnectedIntentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED");
        registerReceiver(powerDisconnectedBroadcastReceiver, powerDisconnectedIntentFilter);

        IntentFilter powerConnectedIntentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED");
        registerReceiver(powerConnectedBroadcastReceiver, powerConnectedIntentFilter);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startServiceButton.setActivated(true);
    }

}
```

`PowerConnectionReceiver.java`

```
public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    // Determine whether the AC is disconnected or not
    private boolean POWER_DISCONNECTED = true;

    PowerConnectionReceiver(boolean disconnected) {
        this.POWER_DISCONNECTED = disconnected;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (POWER_DISCONNECTED) {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.alarm_2);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mediaPlayer.start();
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            //POWER_DISCONNECTED = false;
        } else {
            try {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see AlarmManager anywhere in this code .Its all broadcast receivers .

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean the Alarm of the phone but a general alarm tone that I was using in the app.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is in your complex code.

You register two different instances of `PowerConnectionReceiver` one for "connected" and another for "disconnected" events. So `MediaPlayer` is started in "connected" receiver, and you try to stop `MediaPlayer` in "disconected", but it doesn't play.

You should remove `POWER_DISCONNECTED` field, and handle event in a single instance of receiver. You can register a single receiver for multiple events and use `intent.getAction()` to check how to handle it.

**UPD**
Also you can make your receiver singleton, to prevent multiple registrations, and playing of multiple `MediaPlayer`s

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to find a solution.

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button startServiceButton;
    BroadcastReceiver powerConnectionBroadcastReceiver;
    IntentFilter powerDisconnectedIntentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED");
    IntentFilter powerConnectedIntentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED");


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startServiceButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.startServiceButton);
        powerConnectionBroadcastReceiver = new PowerConnectionBroadcastReceiver();

        startServiceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (startServiceButton.isActivated()) {
                    unregisterReceiver(powerConnectionBroadcastReceiver);
                    startServiceButton.setActivated(false);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    monitorBatteryChanges();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void monitorBatteryChanges() {
        registerReceiver(powerConnectionBroadcastReceiver, powerDisconnectedIntentFilter);
        registerReceiver(powerConnectionBroadcastReceiver, powerConnectedIntentFilter);
        startServiceButton.setActivated(true);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

`PowerConnectionBroadcastReceiver.java`

```
public class PowerConnectionBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED)) {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.alarm_1);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            try {
                if (mediaPlayer != null)
                mediaPlayer.release();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It may not be the best solution but it works :)

Thanks for the help.